# Irreducible polynomials over GF(5)

Tags: code-golf, math, abstract-algebra, polynomials

A polynomial with coefficients in some [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) *F* is called [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) over *F* if it cannot be decomposed into the product of lower degree polynomials with coefficients in *F*.

Consider polynomials over the [Galois field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) GF(5). This field contains 5 elements, namely the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

#### Task

Given a positive integer *n*, compute the number of irreducible polynomials of degree *n* over GF(5). These are simply the polynomials with coefficients in 0-4 which cannot be factored into other polynomials with coefficients in 0-4.

#### Input

Input will be a single integer and can come from any standard source (e.g. STDIN or function arguments). You must support input up to the largest integer such that the output does not overflow.

#### Output

Print or return the number of polynomials that are irreducible over GF(5). Note that these numbers get large rather quickly.

#### Examples

```
In : Out
 1 : 5
 2 : 10
 3 : 40
 4 : 150
 5 : 624
 6 : 2580
 7 : 11160
 8 : 48750
 9 : 217000
10 : 976248
11 : 4438920
```

Note that these numbers form the sequence [A001692](https://oeis.org/A001692) in OEIS.

Comment: PARI/GP 46 bytes on A001692 ;) Is there a time limit?

Comment: @Bruce_Forte Nope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>30</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
ÆF>1’PḄ
ÆDµU5*×Ç€S:Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZGPjHigJlQ4biECsOGRMK1VTUqw5fDh-KCrFM64bmq&input=&args=MTA) or [verify all test cases at once](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZGPjHigJlQ4biECsOGRMK1VTUqw5fDh-KCrFM64bmqCsOH4oKs&input=&args=MSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTE).

#### Algorithm

This uses the formula

$$\text{A001692}(n) = \frac 1 n \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)5^\frac n d$$

from the OEIS page, where \$d | n\$ indicates that we sum over all divisors \$d\$ of \$n\$, and \$\mu\$ represents the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

#### Code

```
ÆF>1’PḄ       Monadic helper link. Argument: d
              This link computes the Möbius function of d.

ÆF            Factor d into prime-exponent pairs.
  >1          Compare each prime and exponent with 1. Returns 1 or 0.
    ’         Decrement each Boolean, resulting in 0 or -1.
     P        Take the product of all Booleans, for both primes and exponents.
      Ḅ       Convert from base 2 to integer. This is a sneaky way to map [0, b] to
              b and [] to 0.

ÆDµU5*×Ç€S:Ṫ  Main link. Input: n

ÆD            Compute all divisors of n.
  µ           Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: divisors of n
   U          Reverse the divisors, effectively computing n/d for each divisor d.
    5*        Compute 5 ** (n/d) for each n/d.

       Ç€     Map the helper link over the (ascending) divisors.
      ×       Multiply the powers by the results from Ç.
         S    Add the resulting products.
          :Ṫ  Divide the sum by the last divisor (n).
```

Comment: I love these Jelly answers to hard math ! :)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
DivisorSum[a=#,5^(a/#)MoebiusMu@#/a&]&
```

Uses the same formula as the Jelly answer.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the named-function operator, but I think it's a byte shorter without: `DivisorSum[n=#,5^(n/#)MoebiusMu@#/n&]&`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:(5**n-sum(d*f(d)for d in range(1,n)if n%d<1))//n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCoMwEAXQdXuK2QgzQbFBhCL1MJFxNFC/IbWLnj7FnW/90u9Yd3TPlEux8R22SQNh4N45NJ/vxuqMVWzPpBRBOWCZ2deQaIRKX16kbVHOgGvwDy/D/ZZyxMHGECl/)

This uses the formula

$$f(n) = \frac 1 n \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)5^\frac n d$$

but applies [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) to turn it into

$$5^n = \sum_{d|n} f(d) d$$

and solves for \$f(n)\$.

**55 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n,d=1:d//n*5**n/n or f(n,d+1)-d*f(d)*(n%d<1)/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoMwEEbhtT3FbISZqSWNIhTRw6RM0wr1NwQ3nj5m@z5eOo/fjuGVcilx@YftbYHQ2eIncw46qsKB9kyRa757eZhGNlFGa7MXhxKrglZQDvh@2Hf9U6Zbk/KKg@smUi4)

Has float precision issues for larger inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 74 bytes

Port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263714/110802) in Scala.

Use the formula: \$5^n = \sum\limits_{d|n} f(d) d\$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwGIT3PsUtQn6hsR1cxBR0c/AhYtNIJP4JbapC6bPHiLcc3zfcTb32OofbY@gTrtoxhk8a2Ew4xYilql7awx4unFR3dvfSUMisukX8UexJxvAWTLVoMXNyHkzSOp@GURjV8cYo1ZB86vhDs7XCEMlpftKO1wzYMEIwjjVapIC2aagcoySOjpNnYcs6FbNWa/4C)

```scala
n=>{(BigInt(5).pow(n)-(1 until n).filter(d=>n%d==0).map(d=>d*f(d)).sum)/n}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
n->ffnbirred(5,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAwCADArxAnSCCxg2P7F43SsCAh/h@73HBxpsmMUujlMlT9ssznxoOdSt9Ehw6Noe0Mkebfig1kLBSdiOoH)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), without built-in, 33 bytes

```
n->sumdiv(n,d,5^d*moebius(n/d))/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADArzRO1ECQwRGeYqJBTAcKAfH7leWGq2cj81RJ4IVN6CNH@hTrqPcjrrncF42u2EZEy5JKUwwenAa3aaiN@J2xgAmTpBgR5Qc)